# Add Remove dynamically grid items cause columnCount must be greater than or equal to the maximum of all grid indices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, layout-inflater, android-gridlayout

I want to add/remove dynamically items in my grid layout. So my xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GridLayoutActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my grid_item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello from me"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the code in my Activity is the following

```
private var counter = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityGridLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            counter++
            addView()
        }

        binding.removeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (counter < 0) return@setOnClickListener
            removeView()
        }
    }

    fun addView() {
        val gridItem = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, binding.gridLayout, false)
        gridItem.id = View.generateViewId()
        val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
        ).also {
            it.width = 0
            it.height = 0
        }
        binding.gridLayout.columnCount = if (counter == 2) 1 else 2
        gridItem.layoutParams = params

        val text = (gridItem as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as TextView
        text.text = "Text ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

        binding.gridLayout.addView(gridItem)
    }

    fun removeView() {
        binding.gridLayout.removeViewAt(counter - 1)
        counter--
        binding.gridLayout.columnCount = if (counter == 2) 1 else 2
    }
```

My problem are the following

1. although my GridLayout has been set to have 2 columns, i want ONE column and TWO rows only when the items number is 2, meaning that i have only 2 items in my layout. Up to now only when adding the second item it works. But when i remove items (like from 3 items to 2 items, i get a crash)
2. I want every new item that is alone in a new row to have width like "match_parent"

How can i achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick.

When `counter == 3`, forcly remove 2 view, and then add one. so `counter` to be 2.

This code achieve your goal.

```kotlin
fun removeView() {
    binding.gridLayout.removeViewAt(counter - 1)
    if (counter == 3) {
        binding.gridLayout.removeViewAt(counter - 2)
        counter--
        addView()
        counter++
    }
    counter--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. We only have to change the orientation of the GridLayout

```
fun addView() {
        val gridItem = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, binding.gridLayout, false)
        gridItem.id = View.generateViewId()
        val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
        ).also {
            it.width = 0
            it.height = 0
        }
        if (counter > 2)
            binding.gridLayout.orientation = GridLayout.HORIZONTAL

        binding.gridLayout.columnCount = if (counter > 2) 2 else 1
        gridItem.layoutParams = params

        val text = (gridItem as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as TextView
        text.text = "Text ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

        binding.gridLayout.addView(gridItem)
    }

    fun removeView() {
        counter--
        binding.gridLayout.removeViewAt(counter)
        if (counter < 3)
            binding.gridLayout.orientation = GridLayout.VERTICAL

    }
```